# How do I access the autofocus options on my Nikon entry-level dSLR?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, camera-settings

I have a Nikon D3300. The menu display does not allow me to change the autofocus options. The ì button shows the MF in the bottom left corner but I have no ability to get into the option to change it. Does anyone have any help for me here? Been a Canon user and this is my first Nikon (used) and don't want this to spoil my experience!

Comment: What specific lens is attached to the camera (full model name, please)?

Answer (score 2):

The mode shown in the status screen is locked if:

- The switch on the lens is set to *M* which forces the lens in *Manual Focus* mode.
- The lens is a *Manual-Focus Only* lens such as Samyang and some Zeiss lenses.
- The lens is damaged or improperly mounted so that the AF contacts do not work.
- The attached AF lens has no AF motor built-in and needs an AF motor from the camera, which the Nikon D3300 does not have. This is the case for AF lenses, while AF-S and AF-P lenses have a built-in focus motor.